# Installing gcc4.8 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6

Tags: linux

I have followed the steps in the similar thread.

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/slc6-devtoolset.repo \ 
http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/devtoolset/slc6-devtoolset.repo
```

this I think worked fine, then

```
sudo yum install devtoolset-2
```

which failed with the error:

```
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 1d1e034b: NOKEY
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-cern


GPG key retrieval failed: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-cern
```

Indeed this file is not in `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg`
on my computer.  Am I supposed to get the file from somewhere and put it there by "hand"?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I used the --nogpgcheck flag

```
yum install --nogpgcheck devtoolset-2
```

In order to then use gcc 4.8.2, I just set the path to the new one

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc
```

Or you can run this command to open a bash shell with devtools-2 enabled :

> scl enable devtoolset-2 'bash'

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is yes, if the gpg key is referenced in the repo file you installed you need the gpg key as well.

It is likely in the same dir as the repo file.

Just make sure you get the right file or the gpg check won't actually protect you.

But why don't you use the gcc that is shipped with RHEL?
There is no need to enable third party repos for gcc as far as I can tell.

If you need a newer version then perhaps you can get it in the red hat software collections repo?
It's a separate subscription but it's free, all you need to do is request it via the support portal.

Comment: Thanks Bram, I don't find the file RPM-GPG-KEY-cern on my computer.  For the project we are setting up, gcc 4.8 or newer is needed and RHEL6 comes with gcc 4.4.7.